# Optimise the selection of two distinct column pairs from the same table

Tags: sql-server-2014, query-performance, optimization, join, query

I need help with rewriting or editing the query/logic to **improve it's performance**. `SQL Server 2014`

I have the table structure specified below. I want to select two column pairs:

(`SourceID` + `SourceName`) and (`TargetID` + `TargetName`)

The query needs to return all distinct `ID` and `Name` pairs within each GroupID.

> Take the following as an example,

```
GroupID    SourceID    SourceName    TargetID    TargetName

1          0           'ant'         2           'dog'
1          1           'bat'         2           'elk'
1          2           'dog'         3           'fox'
1          3           'fox'         4           'pig'
1          4           'pig'         5           'ram'          
1          5           'ram'         6           'owl'
...
```

> As such the result would be:

```
GroupID    LinkID    LinkName

1          0         'ant'
1          1         'bat'
1          2         'dog'
1          2         'elk'
1          3         'fox'
1          4         'pig'
1          5         'ram'
1          6         'owl'
```

> I was able to achieve the results using the following logic

```
SELECT GroupID AS GroupID
  , SourceID   AS LinkID
  , SourceName AS LinkName
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT GroupID AS GroupID
  , TargetID   AS LinkID
  , TargetName AS LinkName
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: You could use the simpler: `SELECT GroupID    AS GroupID
              , SourceID   AS LinkID
              , SourceName AS LinkName
         FROM TABLE
         UNION DISTINCT
         SELECT GroupID    AS GroupID
              , TargetID   AS LinkID
              , TargetName AS LinkName
         FROM TABLE`

Comment: I suggest you add two indexes, on `(GroupID, SourceID, SourceName)` and on `(GroupID, TargetID, TargetName)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I've updated the post for clarity. This however has no impact on the performance.